# Worklight access remote adapter from different server mobilewebapp

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have few adapters deployed in remote uat server.
I want to access them n develop mobile web app in my local worklight server.

Im using IBM Mobilefirst 7.1.0

I tried setting host and contxt path of uat server in mobilewebapp build settings and run the app in my local server. But query call is throwing 404 error.

Can anyone help me in accessing remote adapters in local server.

Comment: If you get a 404 then obviously it is incorrect... Provide an example of how you are trying to set it up (edit the question).

Answer (score 0):

It would've been easier to help you had you provided information such as where are you setting that connection info and what are you setting... since you're getting 404, this would typically mean that you have incorrectly inputted the connection info.

In MobileFirst Studio, right-click on the application folder and select Run As -> Remote Target and Build Settings. There you need to input the server address:

Host: `https://your-server-ip-address:port-number`
Context root: `/myproj` (typically the project name, unless you've specified otherwise in the server.xml of the remote application server).